# interrupted time series with binary outcome in R (specific impact models)

Tags: time-series, logistic, generalized-linear-model, binary-data

I want to fit an interrupted time series model in R. My outcome variable is binary, so I would want to fit a `glm` model and I know the exact time point of my intervention.

How would I specify a certain impact model in R?

Let's say I want to fit a model where the level but not the slope changes and another model for which the slope but not the level changes before and after intervention, how do I actually specify this difference in my `glm`?

I'm basing this on the [Bernal et al. (2016) paper](http://researchonline.lshtm.ac.uk/2550793/1/Int.%20J.%20Epidemiol.-2016-Lopez%20Bernal-ije_dyw098.pdf)  (see page 4)...

I'm particularly interested in the models shown in Figure 2a, 2b, 2c and 2d and how to model these in `R` when my outcome is binary.

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use `glm` you do not take advantage of any pattern which might be present in the series, in the form of autocorrelation, seasonality, etc. There is no provision for that in `glm`. I think state-space models are a suitable alternative; see for instance

MENÉNDEZ, P., TUSELL, F. y WEATHERBURN, D. (2015) *The effects of liquor licensing restrictions on alcohol related violence in NSW, 2008-2013*, **Addiction**, vol. **110**, 1574-1582, DOI:10.1111/add.12951.

In that particular example the outcome is not binary, but assumed normal. But you can fit the same kind of models with discrete responses (see the R package KFAS for instance).

If you tell us more about your problem, we might be able to give further help.